# react-select styles not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-select

I am building a react application using NextJS (v10.0.0) + TailwindCSS (v2.1.1). Currently, I am creating a page that contains a Google Map, for which the [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) (v2.1.1) is being utilized. More specifically, a HOC that injects the returned values from the `useJsApiLoader` hook. This HOC fetches the google maps library and creates a script tag for it within the document.

When attempting to import and render the `react-select` component, its elements' classes exist in the DOM, but on further inspection, no styles exist for such classes, i.e. the component works as expected but looks unstyled, and even its accesibility text is visible sometimes. The issue goes away once I remove the code responsible for loading the library.

This problem will most likely occur with any HOCs or hooks that execute tasks similar to those of the `useJSApiLoader`, but I would like to understand why this could happening and what I can do to solve it. So far I have taken this approaches with no luck:

- Load `react-select` dynamically with `next/dynamic` (no ssr)
- Refactor the component wrapped by the HOC to contain the `useJsApiLoader` hook within it.
- Isolate a map component and load the library in there.

A minimal reproduction repo can be found at https://github.com/noe-lc/react-select-gm. The Select component's styles will be loaded correctly when the `withGoogleMaps` hook is removed from the `pages/index.js` file

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `Select` component's styles were not loading correctly when attempting to render it while fetching the gmaps library. So I tried to render the component than contains it **after** fetching the library and now everything seems to be working fine.

I did this with `LoadScriptNext` https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#loadscriptnext, which provides a way to execute a callback when the library is loaded.

PS Still, I would like to understand why this problem was happening.